# <f:ajax> contains an unknown id :someid when used in <ui:repeat>

Tags: jsf-2

My code snippet:

```
<ui:repeat var="o">
   <h:panelGroup id="someid">
      <ui:repeat>
         // HTML
      </ui:repeat>
   </h:panelGroup>

   <div>
      <h:form>
          <h:commandButton action="#{o.doSomething}">
              <f:ajax event="action" render=":someid" />
          </h:commandButton>
      <h:form>
   </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

Why didn't `<f:ajax>` find `someid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. The `<ui:repeat>` prepends the client ID with its own ID and an index. All those panelgroups get IDs like `j_id1:0:someid`, `j_id1:1:someid`, `j_id1:2:someid`, etc. The following is supposed to work in your particular construct:

```
<f:ajax render=":#{component.parent.parent.clientId}:someid" />
```

This will prepend the `<ui:repeat>`'s current client ID dynamically. It however only works when you're using with [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/) instead of [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net). The `<ui:repeat>` is broken in many ways in Mojarra. They have scheduled many fixes for 2.2.

An alternative is to group them in a common `NamingContainer` component like `<h:form>`, so that you can use a relative ID.

```
<ui:repeat var="o">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGroup id="someid">
            <ui:repeat>
                // HTML
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <div>
            <h:commandButton action="#{o.doSomething}">
                <f:ajax event="action" render="someid" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </div>
    <h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks . But i want to render entire outer ui:repeat . So , how can i do it ?

Comment: Oh? You didn't made that clear in the question. Just put the outer `<ui:repeat>` in a `<h:panelGroup id="foo">` and use `render=":foo"` (or whatever its *actual* client ID is, rightclick page in browser and do *View Source* to find it).